# How to handle click of links in jQuery touchSwipe block

Tags: javascript, jquery, touchswipe

I have a block of links handled by jQuery touchSwipe plugin. When I tap a single link from mobile device, it doens't follow the url stored at "href" attribute. I use plugin option "click". Basically it works, for example with alert(). But how to get default behaviour of button click and just follow url.

```
container.swipe({
    click: function(event, target) {
        $(target).click(); //nothing happen
    },
    threshold: 75,
    excludedElements: "button, input, select, textarea, .noSwipe",
});
```